# How would I make this LED display only display only full or empty circles?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I'm currently modeling this robot and I'm trying to create a LED display material for the eyes. I'm using a Voronoi texture to act as a masking for the eye texture but the eyes are showing halfway through some circles.
[image]

I want it so that the material will only show a full circle or no circles at all.

Here is my node setup:
[image]

This is the eye texture:

[image]

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You can quantize UV coordinates using vector math node (snap):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the 'Position' output of your regular *Voronoi* as your texture coordinate will quantize the UV that's fed to it:

[image]

.. some function of the 'Distance' output will control the spread of illumination, or other features, per-cell.

This has the advantage that everything is controlled from one place.. the 'Scale' of the *Voronoi*:

[image]